# Database Relational Table Person and Address

Tags: database, relational-database

What is the appropriate way of handling a situation where you have a table Person that has persons name, phone number, and other information and a second table Address?

Should you specify the Address primary key as a foreign key in the Person table or is it best to have a Person_has_Address with foreign keys to the person and the address?

I have begun to notice it is quite cumbersome to use foreign key constraint as it then requires you to have to input the address first then the person where if you use a Person_has_Address you can start with the Person or the Address table.

Comment: "I have begun to notice it is quite cumbersome to use foreign key constraint as it then requires you to have to input the address first then the person where if you use a Person_has_Address you can start with the Person or the Address table."  - cumbersome? No. Correct: Yes!  Depends how much you like orphaned data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between Person and Address is in general many-to-many: multiple Persons can reside/work/vacation at the same address, and each Person can have different residential/work/vacation addresses.

You should build separate Person and Address tables as well as a `PersonAddress` table with an FK relationship to each of `Person` and `Address`.

Answer (score 0):

If a Person can only ever have 2 addresses, then the simple way to model this is to have `Address1Id` and `Address2Id` as foreign key columns in the Person table.

BUT if a person can have many addresses, create a many-to-many intermediate table `PersonAddress`

```
PersonAddress
=============

PersonId  (FK to Person.Id)
AddressId (FK to Address.Id)
```